# HTML/CSS background does not match on other screen sizes

Tags: html, css, background

I am doing some HTML/CSS homework for my school and now I have a trouble with my background in the header, which does not match on other screen sizes.

```css
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(photo.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul class="main-nav">

      <li class="active"><a href=""> HOME </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> SERVICES </a></li>
      <li><a href="../Web/about.html"> ABOUT </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> CONTACT </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> NEWS </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> FAQ </a></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="hero">
    <h1>Overcome Yourself</h1>

    <div class="button">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-one"> Watch Video </a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-two"> Explore More </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
html{ 
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover; /* for old firefox / Safari */
 background-size: cover; /* standard version */
}
```

EDIT :
Can you try this solution by applying the CSS code to the html tag ?
Does it match with your problem ?

Comment: Questions for the OP should be in the form of comments on their question, not as an answer to the question.

Comment: It's responsive with my size of monitor screen (1920x1080), but it isn't responsive with other sizes. I want to set up it for matching on all monitor sizes without scrolling a screen or white stripe on the right side of screen (for the example).

Comment: I edited my answer @Justin.
TomHackKey,  try my edited answer, it will display your image in the background, without changing the ratio high/width of your image.

Comment: did it fix your problem ?

Comment: No, the background disappear with the no-repeat center fixed code.

Comment: Oh... without the height it disapper.

Comment: Ok :) I think it's possible.

Comment: feel free to mark my answer as the good one if it fixed your problem :) Thank you in advance